# Typechecking with PropTypes gives me an error even though the props show properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, typechecking, react-proptypes

I am type-checking my components with `prop-types`, but even though I am getting the values properly in the right type, I still get the error message as following:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `id` is marked as required in
>   `NewChannel`, but its value is `undefined`.

```
const NewChannel = props => {    
    const { id } = props.match.params
    return(
    //some logic
    )
}

NewChannel.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default React.memo(NewChannel)
```

When I `console.log` the props `id`, it's not undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You type checking says: `props` will have an id field like: `props.id`. But you are getting id from `props.match.params`. That is why it is complaining.

Comment: How do I get around this?

Comment: Maybe something like:

NewChannel.propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
      params: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
      })
    })
}

Comment: You can check all the possibilities here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: hmm.. thank you, but I'm still getting `undefined`.  I've tried with `object` instead of `shape`, but still the same thing

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by: `I'm still getting undefined`?  The id is in `props` or in `props.match.params?

Comment: The code you suggested causes `Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the prop-types package. Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them.`

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems to be working.  Can I ask you why you chose to use `shape`?  React Doc seems to indicate that it's for `An object taking on a particular shape`

Comment: I used shape because is what you use for object. For example in your case you want to validate that `match` is an object and not a string or number or array. Later you want to validate that `match` as a field `params` that is also an object and finally that `params` has a field `id` that is a string. You could also use `PropTypes.exact` if you know the exact shape of the object. But in this case I think you are dealing with an object that will have more fields but you don't care them, so you only check for the once that you care.